# Animated opacity fade in delay - set opacity of image to 0 untill X seconds?

Tags: css, html

I have an image display then fade out at the beginning of a banner.

HTML -

```
<div id="logo-fade"><img src="http://www.ison-  distribution.com/uploads/arty/halo-logo.png"/></div>

/* logo animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    100% { opacity: 0; }
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
    100% { opacity: 0; }
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    100% { opacity: 0; }
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
}

#logo-fade {
    width:970px;
    height:250px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeout 5s ease-out forwards ;
       -moz-animation: fadeout 5s ease-out forwards ;
            animation: fadeout 5s ease-out forwards ;
}
```

I'd like an image to fade in 7s before the end of the video (playing in the background) and remain.

Everything is in place, but the final image opacity is 100% throughout the timeline, untill it fades in at the end.

[example](http://www.ison-distribution.com/uploads/arty/halo-vapour-html5-dirt-1160314.html)

```
/* banner animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    100% { opacity: 0; }
    50%  { opacity: 0; }
    25%  { opacity: 0; }
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
100% { opacity: 1; }
    50%  { opacity: 0; }
    25%  { opacity: 0; }
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadein {
    100% { opacity: 0; }
    50%  { opacity: 0; }
    25%  { opacity: 0; }
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
}

#banner-fade {
    width:970px;
    height:250px;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 4s ease-in 12s forwards ;
       -moz-animation: fadein 4s ease-in 12s forwards ;
            animation: fadein 4s ease-in 12s forwards ;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate and supply a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qjax0809/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do a Jsfiddle for you, see here https://jsfiddle.net/sgvcqc4r/

just that :

```
$('#logo-fade').hide().delay(9000).fadeIn(2000);
$('#banner-fade').hide().delay(7000).fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Hi Greg, this is very close ! But the 'logo-fade' at the start was ok ;) Just the 'banner fade' was displaying at the start also, I only need it to fade in at the end.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you :) I will just change the timing slightly but that's great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not much easier to use the fadeIn() function in jQuery?
http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: If possible I would Like to use just CSS, like the Halo logo fade out at the start.